# Rank of concatenated matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B,C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ be full row rank matrices ($m,p<n$). If

$\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix}$,

then is the following true:

$\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ C \end{bmatrix} = \operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix}$?

Here are my thoughts.
I understand that the "if-part" of my statement says that $C$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ and $B$: $C = L_1 A + L_2 B$. But in order to the "then-part" to be true, $B$ would have to be a linear combination of $A$ and $C$: $B = L_3 A + L_4 C$.

This seems to be true if there exists some $L_2$ that is invertible, so that

$L_2^{-1} C = L_2^{-1}L_1 A + B$

$B = L_3 A + L_4 C$, where $L_3 = -L_2^{-1}L_1$ and $L_4 = L_2^{-1}$.

Is there any condition that guarantees that $L_2^{-1}$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$ \eqalign{A &= [0 \ 1]\cr
                B &= [1 \ 0]\cr
                C &= [0 \ 1]\cr}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  Try $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\\
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\\
C=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that $A,B,C$ are full row rank matrices. Question edited!